# como deixar a div exterior invisivel (hidden), mas o seu interior vísivel?

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/wf9ghbc7/

**Javascript**

Estou fazendo um jogo de sortear números aleatoriamente:
Gostaria de fazer algo parecido com um jogo de slot machine. Ou seja, apenas um número deve aparecer dentro de uma div e os números no exterior devem ficam invisiveis.

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,107,8,9,107,8,9,107,8,9,107,8,9,107,8,9,107,8,9,107,8,9,107,8,9,107,8,9,107,8,9,107,8,9,10,11,12,13,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,14,15];
var contador = 1;
var novoTopo = array.length * 200 * -1;
$('#valores').css({top: + novoTopo});
for(var i =0;i<array.length;i++){
    $("#valores").append("<div id='result"+contador+"' classs='name'>"+array[i]+"</div>");
    contador++;
}

<div id="valores">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para que você obtenha esse resultado, a sua div `id="valores"`, que possui animação e contém os demais números do "jogo" deve estar dentro de uma outra div, para que você faça o controle de layout nela, já que será uma div fixa.

Para que ela tenha o comportamento esperado, você deve definir os parametros de width, height e overflow, por exemplo:

```
.valores_wrap {
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:60px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

A propriedade 'overflow', que define o scroll da div, quando definida como `hidden` irá desabilitar o scroll da div e impedir que tudo que esteja "fora" dela apareça no layout. Com isso você pode obter o resultado esperado.

Veja este exemplo que fiz com o seu fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wf9ghbc7/10/

Obs.: modifiquei um valor no seu `JS` pois ele estava deslocando o número do jogo 10px para baixo.